# MS.Internal.NamedObject is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, mfc

I am having an issue almost exactly like the one listed in this link.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3d0eae67-2cd8-4c06-888a-650a811f1fcf/type-msinternalnamedobject-in-assembly-windowsbase-is-not-marked-as-serializable?forum=wpf

My problem is like the original author's, having a .NET remoting proxy as the binding source for a control. In my case the control in question is a TabControl, the itemsource property of which I am binding to a property on an interface type whos realization was in native code.

The series of links threaded to by the one above make mention that there are workarounds. Microsoft claims a fix, but it seems reserved for .net 4.5 which I am unable to move to (i'm stuck in 4.0). In regards to the workarounds, unfortunately I cannot for the life of me figure out where to apply any of the workarounds discussed as they seem to be not detailed.

What I have found on my own at least is that Object.Equals() is being called on a TransparentProxy object, which is binding source interface instance, and the instance of object stored in the contents of the BindingExpressionBase's EffectiveTargetNullValue property. This instance of object stored at this property happens to be of type MS.Internal.NamedObject.

My guess is that when a object represented by a .Net remoting proxy is part of a comparison operation, both objects in the comparison are attempted to be serialized or referenced depending on whether or not the object inherits from MarshalByRefObj. In my case, the MS.Internal.NamedObject type is not marked as such, and when the comparison its made, causes me a Serialization exception.

I can make an attempt to provide code that boils this down, however my project is part of a large MFC/WPF application. It'd take me a long time.
The MFC application loads plugins, one of which, when activated is to provide a child WPF window accessible to the MFC native c++ plugin via COM interop. The WPF window and its service are launched in an appdomain separate from the one automatically created when doing native to managed COM interop. The two app domains communicate through a combination of WCF and COM Event sinks. The data source for the WPF window is passed from the original MFC appdomain (via com interop) to the other, then a signal is sent to notify the application in the other domain to read data, and update its views. The .NET remoting comes into play as i use the AppDomain.SetData method to make the data available to the WPF appdomain from the MFC one. The data is intrinsically a ComObj at this point, served up to the WPF window by a TransparentProxy.

Ultimately i need to know if a WPF Tab control can bind its item source to a COM object served up by a transparent proxy that crosses appdomains. If this is possible, then is my Serialization exception due to the bug in .net 4.0 as stated by the link, and if so, is there workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: I have just written a test that shows you can 100% bind to a MarshalByRefObject that was proxied over from another AppDomain.

Comment: A bit more information. It seems the culprit is two way binding in one fashion or another. Specifically two way binding set on the SelectedValue property of a TabControl (though i'm sure isn't limited to TabControl).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered precisely this issue when binding a collection of .NET remoting proxies to a WPF `ItemsControl`. Again, a comparison operation featured at the root of the exception stack trace. `DataTemplate` binding and control binding within the `DataTemplate` actually worked for the first couple of calls (the `ItemsControl.DataContext` was being taken from a list selected item) but then the exception was raised.

The fact that the proxy bindings worked initially made me suspect that the issue lay with how the `ItemsControl` was handling its internal `ItemsSource` binding state.

My workaround is to not use the `ItemsSource` binding but to manually create the `ContentControl` and add to the `Items` collection. The `ContentControl` will query the `UserControl.Resources` for a matching `DataTemplate`:

```
var contentControl = new ContentControl { Content = input };
_inputsItemsControl.Items.Add(contentControl);
```

The OP was binding a `TabControl`, which is an `ItemsControl` subclass, so the same approach should work.